# Convert Extended to Time

Tags: delphi

I need to convert extended values to time format. For example :

```
3.50 represents  00:03:50
62.02 represents 01:02:02
73.70 represents 01:14:10
```

I have tried the following function to convert the Hour and Minutes part but I don't have any idea on how to convert the Seconds' part.

```
function ConvertToTime(AValue: Extended): TDateTime;
begin
    Result:=  EncodeTime(trunc(ArticleRec.Quantity) div 60,trunc(ArticleRec.Quantity) mod 60,0,0);
end;
```

Thanking you in anticipation for your help.

Comment: If you're going to work with duration (not with the time of a day), then you can use [`TTimeSpan`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.TimeSpan.TTimeSpan) record (if you're still using Delphi XE2) instead of the `TDateTime` data type (because you would not be easily able to represent value exceeding 24 hours). For example `TTimeSpan.FromMinutes` function can give you a time span record from your format.

Comment: ok , yes I am using XE2. Thank you I shall try the TTimeSpan.

Comment: Thanks again to David Heffernan and TLama for their solutions. I used the function from David Heffernan to convert the double value to seconds , after that I used the TTimeSpan.FromSeconds and formatted the TimeSpan to HH:MM:SS duration: 1.Total := TTimeSpan.FromSeconds(ConvertWeirdTimeFormatToSeconds(62.02)) 2. Format('%2d:%.2d:%.2d', [Total.days * 24 + Total.Hours, Total.Minutes,Total.Seconds])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fractional part is obtained like this:

```
var
  SecondsFrac: Double;
....
SecondsFrac := Frac(Value);
```

And then you can convert from a floating point fractional value in the range 0 to 1 to an integer in the range 0 to 100 like this:

```
var
  Seconds: Integer;
....
Seconds := Round(SecondsFrac*100);
```

This is a pretty weird way to store time though. You have to deal with the fact that when `Seconds >= 60` you need to increment the minutes, and decrement `Seconds` by `60`.

I guess I'd do that by converting the time into seconds, and going from there:

```
function ConvertWeirdTimeFormatToSeconds(const Value: Double): Integer;
var
  SecondsFrac: Double;
begin
  SecondsFrac := Frac(Value);
  Result := Round(SecondsFrac*100) + Trunc(Value)*60;
end;
```

You can then decode the seconds into distinct parts like this:

```
procedure DecodeSeconds(Value: Integer; out Hours, Minutes, Seconds: Integer);
begin
  Seconds := Value mod 60;
  Value := Value div 60;
  Minutes := Value mod 60;
  Value := Value div 60;
  Hours := Value;
end;
```

Which makes me think it might be better to just store the time in an integer number seconds from midnight. It makes far more sense to use a standard format, in my view.

I see no reason to use `Extended` here, or indeed anywhere for that matter. It's a non-standard type that due to its strange size and consequent alignment issues tends to perform poorly. And it's only supported on x86.

Comment: Thank you for you help. Which standard format you advise me to use?

Comment: It depends on what your goal is. I don't know what your motivation is.

Comment: Based on the specification, the time is in extended. I was catering for only hours and minutes conversion before, now I need to cater for the second's part also. Is there any other simpler way to represent the second's part in digit.

Comment: Store it as `Seconds / 60` is one choice. However, using `Extended` is surely a bad design choice. A lot of people don't really understand the downsides of `Extended` and perceive benefits that are in fact non-existent. Who made that choice?

Comment: There are 86400 seconds in a day. Even single precision can represent that accurately. `Extended` is non-standard, does not exist anywhere other than 32 bit x86, and performs poorly. Your client is ill-informed.

Comment: @ David Heffernan : Yes for sure. 
@ TLama  1441 must represents 24:01:00

Comment: @Veela Well, that's not a valid time of day, is it?

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually, the time is actually a representation of duration in my case. So 24:01:00 is valid in this case. :( I used time representation , my code would crash when doing 1441 isn't it?
I am really sorry. I didn't thought of this case

Comment: A time span is different from a time. Anyway, I think I answered the question that you asked.